# Geopy not supported on Google App Engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, geopy

I am looking to use geopy with Python 2.7 on GAE.  However, when I deploy the code I get the following error:

> appcfg.py: error: Error parsing C:\myPrograms\Google
>   AppEngine\Programs\Balefire\app.yaml: the library "geopy" is not
>   supported

My app.yaml has:

```
libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: latest
- name: pycrypto
  version: "2.6"
- name: ssl
  version: latest
- name: geopy
  version: latest
```

Does GAE really not support this library and if so what are the alternatives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The libraries that you can specify versions of in `app.yaml` are listed in https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries27

`geopy` isn't in that list. But if `geopy` is pure python (which https://github.com/geopy/geopy appears to be at a quick glance), it may be possible to include it as part of your application.

Comment: I added it manually based on the instructions on the page you linked and it worked.  Thanks!